# How to set value dynamically in AMP forms

Tags: html, amp-html, amp-bind

I want to set value of second select dropdown based on the first dropdown. Is there a way to set value of select in AMP.

```
<select name="cars" on="change:
            AMP.setState({
                 bikes:'bike2'       
    }) id="card">
  <option value="">Select cars</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select name="bikes" id="bikes">
  <option value="">Select bikes</option>
  <option value="bike1">bike1</option>
  <option value="bike2">bike2</option>
  <option value="bike3">bike3</option>
  <option value="bike4">bike4</option>
</select>
```

If I select some option in first dropdown and then I select second option.
If I go back and set first dropdown to empty value that should make the second dropdown also empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by using **amp-bind**, **amp-list** and **amp-mustache**

[**Here is working link**](https://codepen.io/bachchasingh/pen/qYWEOj)

**Add js code on head section**

First we include `amp-bind` to track the page state and update the `<amp-list>` data source.

```
 <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
```

Next we include `amp-list` to request and display the dropdowns and their options.

```
<script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
```

Finally, we include `amp-mustache` to render the mustache templates inside the `<amp-list>`s.

```
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
```

**Add html code in body section**

```
 <amp-list height="25" layout="fixed-height" src="https://jsonblob.com/api/527428a6-41f4-11e8-bbe4-1dfe6c86f2cb">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
         <select id="car" on="
        change:
          AMP.setState({
            bikes: dropdown.items[0].cars.filter(x => x.name == event.value)[0]
          })"
      >
        <option value="">Select cars</option>
        {{#cars}}
          <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
        {{/cars}}
      </select>
    </template>
</amp-list>
<amp-list height="25" layout="fixed-height" [src]="bikes || 'https://jsonblob.com/api/527428a6-41f4-11e8-bbe4-1dfe6c86f2cb'" src="https://jsonblob.com/api/527428a6-41f4-11e8-bbe4-1dfe6c86f2cb">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
       <select [disabled]="!bikes" disabled id="bike">
        {{^bikes}}<option value=""></option>{{/bikes}}
        {{#bikes.0}}<option value="">Select bikes</option>{{/bikes.0}}
        {{#bikes}}<option value="{{.}}">{{.}}</option>{{/bikes}}
      </select>
    </template>
</amp-list>
<amp-state id="dropdown" src="https://jsonblob.com/api/527428a6-41f4-11e8-bbe4-1dfe6c86f2cb"></amp-state>
```

**Note :** create json according to drop down like https://jsonblob.com/api/527428a6-41f4-11e8-bbe4-1dfe6c86f2cb

[**For more information visit**](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/linked_dropdowns/)

**UPDATED ANSWER**

[**Visit the working URL**](https://codepen.io/bachchasingh/pen/debVXa)

**Updated HTML code**

```
<select on="change:AMP.setState({ option: event.value })" class="m1">
  <option value="0">Select cars</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="bikes" id="bikes">
    <option [selected]="option == 0" value="">Select bikes</option>
    <option hidden [hidden]="option == 0" value="bike1">bike1</option>
    <option hidden [hidden]="option == 0" value="bike2">bike2</option>
    <option hidden [hidden]="option == 0" value="bike3">bike3</option>
    <option hidden [hidden]="option == 0" value="bike4">bike4</option>
</select>

<input [checked]="option != 0" type="radio" />
<span>Select Radio</span>
```

Comment: I dont need dynamic dropdown. Its a static dropdown why an extra request just to static dropdown. Its not only resetting the dropdown I need to reset radio buttons as well.

Comment: Where is radio button in question?

Comment: That doesn't work.Please select first option then select second option. Now go back to first select emtpy option and Second option should also become select empty option i.e first option

Comment: @SusheelSingh check now i have updated my codepen as you suggest

Comment: please update your answer so that it would useful for others code section